# How to use Visual Studio to connect to Acuamatica server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, acumatica

I'm trying  to connect to this server using visual studio 
 [image]

But I'm getting below Error

[image]

This is how i config

Comment: What is the point to connect to an FTP server from VS? The protocol in your second screenshot is FTP instead of HTTP(S).

Comment: What do you mean saying "Trying to connect"? From VS you can try to debug Acumatica, or open Acumatica as web site project.

Comment: Can you show me how to open the source code of this server using VS ?